# Send SMS with Node.JS SerialPort

Tags: javascript, node.js, serial-port, sms

I'm trying to do what the title says using an enfora modem for that purpose. However, even though it works correctly in minicom, it won't work in my node.js application.
Here's the code that I'm using:

```
serialPort.write('AT+CMGF=1\r');
serialPort.write('AT+CMGS="02122323232"\r');
serialPort.write('mensaje'+String.fromCharCode(26)+'\r');
```

I've also tried replacing **String.fromCharCode(26)** with the following options. none of which has worked.

```
'\^z'
'^z'
'^(z)'
'\^(z)'
'<ctrl+Z>'
'<ctrl-Z>'
'\#'
'#'
'\u001A'
Buffer([0x1A])
```

I sincerely believe that this is the problematic part of the code, because i get an OK message from the first 2 lines, but the third one returns nothing, because it doesn't get processed.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    setTimeout(function(){
        serialPort.write('AT+CMGF=1\r')
        setTimeout(function(){
            serialPort.write('AT+CMGS=\"02142323232\"\r')
            setTimeout(function(){
                serialPort.write('test sms\r')
                setTimeout(function(){
                    serialPort.write('\x1A')
                }, 100);
            }, 100);
         }, 100);
     }, 100);
```

Comment: Ah, so the modem couldn't keep up?  You can clean this up quite a bit.  Create a write function that writes to a queue, and an interval that reads from that queue, writing to the modem.  You might also be able to enable hardware flow control to solve this problem for you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `0x1a` is the byte you need to send, you just need to send it in a buffer correctly.  You cannot simply concatenate.  If you do, you end up with literally the string `mensaje\u001a`, instead of the character for `0x1a`.

Try this:

```
serialPort.write('mensaje');
serialPort.write(new Buffer[0x1a]);
serialPort.write('\r');
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this later or tomorrow, depending on whether I get access to the office's server

Comment: Oh, also. The buffer part I'm not sure what it means, I saw it in another stackoverflow post and it's supposed to be the same as control z. Which is why I tried with String.fromCharCode(26)

Comment: ok i tried it, it still doesn't work, and in fact throws error. No details, it just says error. I guess I have to find another way to send control z to the serialport. Any suggestions?

Comment: @arrigonfr What serial port API are you using?  If it doesn't accept buffers, I would suggest finding a new one.

Comment: i did it. i till post the code as an answer in a few minutes

Comment: oh, and to answer your question. I was using npm serialport module for node.js

Comment: I am not able to send sms if string has spaces e.g "myTest" is sent but "my test sms" doest get sent. I have no knowledge about gsm protocols. What I should do?